# "Which child of its parent am I?" in JQuery

Tags: jquery, dom, indexing, children

I have the html code:

```
<div id="all">
    <div id="1">
        <div id="1-1">
        </div>
        <div id="1-2">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="2">
        <div id="2-1">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have somewhere in my JQuery code:

```
var obj = jQuery("#1-2");
```

I want to check which child of his parent (**relative to his parent**) is obj (in that case it should return 1 for second index).

I have tried (with no result):

```
alert(obj.index());
```

Comment: Are you checking after the elements have been loaded into the DOM?

Comment: Some browser don't work well with HTML element id's that start with a number. And I don't think it is valid either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code is returning the correct index. I think you just need implement code in [jquery ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).

```
$(function() {
   var obj = jQuery("#1-2");
   alert( obj.index() );
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tCBKM/2/)**

Comment: Oh, how stupid I am. Indeed thanks, guess not ready was the problem here :) People at stackoverflow - you are brilliant and helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
var obj = jQuery("#1-2");
var parentId = obj.parent().attr('id');
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/SADzX/)

Comment: I don't want to get the index of the parent. I want to know which children of it's parent it is. For "#1-1" it should be 0, for "#1-2" 1, for "1" 0, for "2" 1.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var $obj = $("#1-2");

// Need to check th index for this structure

var $parent = $('div > div > div');
// You want to find the index of your selector
// based on the selector that follows the above structure

console.log($($parent).index($obj))
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/dYhjd/)**

Comment: op's code works fine - it just looks like the selector isn't returning any elements therefore getting a -1 return value so `1.` It's running before the element exists in the DOM or `2.` the selector is wrong

Comment: This also works. But the problem was not ready doc structure, as the thecodeparadox mentioned.